# Extract last word in DataFrame column

Tags: python, pandas, list

This has to be so simple - but I can't figure it out.  I have a "name" column within a DataFrame and I'm trying to reverse the order of ['First Name', 'Middle Name', 'Last Name']  to  ['Last Name', 'First Name', 'Middle Name'].

Here is my code:

```
for i in range(2114):
bb = a['Approved by User'][i].split(" ",2)[2]
aa = a['Approved by User'][i].split(" ",2)[0]
a['Full Name]'] = bb+','+aa
```

Unfortunately I keep getting IndexError: list index out of range with the current code.

This is what I want:

Old column Name| Jessica Mary Simpson

New column Name| Simpson Jessica Mary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem is in your data, here is your solution in pandas text functions [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html), indexing and [`Series.str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html):

```
df['Full Name'] = df['Approved by User'].str.split(n=2).str[::-1].str.join(' ')
print (df)
       Approved by User             Full Name
0  Jessica Mary Simpson  Simpson Mary Jessica
1              John Doe              Doe John
2                  Mary                  Mary
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is to split the string and `join`it later on in a function.
like so:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {"name": ["Jessica Mary Simpson"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
a = df.name.str.split()
a = a.apply(lambda x: " ".join(x[::-1])).reset_index()
print(a)
```

output:

```
    index   name
0   0   Simpson Mary Jessica
```

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, you could try following.
Let's say following is the df:

```
    fullname
0   Jessica Mary Simpson
1   Ravinder avtar singh
2   John jonny janardan
```

Here is the code:

```
df['fullname'].replace(r'^([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) (.*)$', r'\3 \1 \2',regex=True)
```

***OR***

```
df['fullname'].replace(r'^(\S*) (\S*) (.*)$', r'\3 \1 \2',regex=True)
```

output will be as follows:

```
0   Simpson Jessica Mary
1   singh Ravinder avtar
2   janardan John jonny
```